# Can I write a Flutter app to simulate location (Fake GPS) on iOS?

Tags: ios, flutter

Can I write a Flutter mobile app to simulate location (Fake GPS) on iOS?

I know that I can connect my mobile phone to Macbook, then use Xcode's Simulate Location function, and modify the GPX file to simulate the location.

I want to convert this function into a mobile APP interface, and doesn't need to be connected to Macbook. Is there any way?

Comment: No. You cannot do this